# Relations and transitivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am just now starting to grasp the concepts of 
transitivity in relations and I have the following question:

In my textbook, it is noted that 
$R = \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)\}$ is not transitive.

How can that be right?

There are only two elements in this relation and there aren't any "steps" that aren't covered.

It was explained to us that a relation is not transitive when you can not perform a two-step action with one step. However there isn't any possible action in the $R$ above that requires more than one step.

To give an example, this is transitive:
$\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,3),(3,4),(4,4)\}$

But this is not:
$\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,4),(4,4)(4,1)\}$

But that is obviously because there isn't a $(3, 1)$

I can not see a fundamental difference between the two from the first example.

Thank you for your help

EDIT:

Apparently, this also isn't transitive and I have no idea why:

$R_5 = \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1), (4, 4)\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitivity simply means if $(x,y) \in R, (y,z) \in R$, then $(x,z)\in R$. In the first case, $(2,1), (1,2) \in R$, but $(2,2) \notin R$.

The last one is not transitive because $(2,1), (1,4) \in R$, but $(2,4)\notin R$

Comment: So if we have (1,2) and (2,1), we also need the (1, 1) and (2, 2) elements?

Comment: Yes. Think of drawing a chain connecting the points (in 2 dimensions) if they are related. If you can connect two points with a sequence of chains, you should be able to connect it with a single chain :)

Comment: But then how can we have that R={(3,4)} is transitive when we don't have (3, 3) and (4, 4)? Or do we only need these when we have two elements like so: {(3, 4), (4,3)}?
Sorry for all the retarded questions guys, I am just trying to get a grasp of this concept. Thanks for the help

Comment: Exactly. If $(3,4), (4,3)\in R$, then $(3,3)$ and $(4,4)$ must be in $R$, but the converse is not true.

Comment: Thank you so much @Prahlad Vaidyanathan!